# How Does the Preprocessor Process "#include" Directives?

Tags: c, include, c-preprocessor

What exactly does the preprocessor do when it encounters an `#include` directive in a source code?

I assume it replaces the `#include` with the contents of the included file, but I wanted something stronger than my assumption.

Is there any reason not to type the contents of the included file straight into the source code rather than `#include` it other than it being nicer on the eye?

Comment: It's rather easy to find an answer on Google, but since I couldn't find one on Stack Overflow, I decided to just ask. I'm sorry if this was the wrong decision (or if I simply missed a very bold question which does contain an answer to this).

Comment: To be fair I never really validated it but it copy-pastes (includes) the contents into the file. That's why you need things like include guards.

Comment: Ah, it's perfectly fine to ask things you find on Google and it's also perfectly fine to answer your own question with well written answers. It's probably best to make the question more concise though.

Comment: "is there any reason not to simply type the contents of the included file straight into the source code" -> Avoiding code duplication, mainly.

Comment: The lexical transformation rules are described in the C standard, where you can easily satisfy all your formal curiosity.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, I tried to make it a little more concise now, I hope that's okay...

Comment: @KerrekSB, Sorry :/ I thought it would be nice to have this on Stack Overflow to increase the accessibility of this information for those times you find yourself thinking of preprocessors during your casual Googling time...

Comment: @ShayHacohen: I'm not sure that SO is a good place for copy-pasting large amounts of standardese. Something like [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/translation_phases) seems to be better suited to that task.

Comment: most programmers, me included, prefer to only write code once.  A header file makes it easy to implement that desire, as (in any project beyond a very few files, (like 1 or 2 files) a set of header files saves typing thousands of characters.  And when a item in a header file needs modification. it only has to be modified 1 (one) place rather than having to hunt through (possibly) hundreds of files looking for that same code to modify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The preprocessor will replace the `#include` statement with the contents of the file.

The advantage of using `#include` instead of simply pasting the content of the file is that, if the header file is modified, all you have to do is recompile the source file. Had you pasted the content of the file then you would have had to replace that with the new version of the header file.

Also, if you `#include` a file in several places (as happens with constants and type definition files) you don't have to modify all repeated declarations, the multiple times included file makes one place of change instead of several.

Answer (score 1):

From my copy of the draft C11 standard section 6.10.2 paragraph 3

> A preprocessing directive of the form

`# include "q-char-sequence" new-line`

> causes the replacement of that directive by the entire contents of the source file identified by the
>   specified sequence between the " delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

That's the point of `#include` files.

Take `#include <stdio.h>` which is a distributed library header. If you have a suite of project source files you would possibly have to paste the content of `stdio.h` into every one. The whole point of `#include` files is that you don't have to.

Now take `#include "mycommon.h"` which is your local commonly used project functions. If you don't use `#include` every time you modify your local `mycommon.h` you will have to re-paste it into all your source files.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any reason not to type the contents of the included file straight into the source code rather than #include it other than it being nicer on the eye?

It is not a matter of being easy on the eye.

The primary purpose of a header file is to have common *declarations* for function-prototypes and data-objects that are *defined* in separate translation units.  Most non-trivial applications comprise multiple modules in separate translation units separately compiled and linked.  A function or data-object must be *defined* in only one translation unit, but may be referenced in many - all of which must have a correctly matching *declaration* for the link to succeed.  The simplest and least error prone method of ensuring the *declarations* are correct in every translation unit is to use a header file; entering the same information in multiple translation units would be very difficult to maintain.

If on the other hand your translation unit contains functions and data that are accessed only within that translation unit (or your application is a single translation unit), then the corresponding declarations may indeed appear in the same source file, and should also be declared `static` to explicitly disallow external linkage.

Consider for example the standard library headers such as stdio.h.  You could for example enter the prototype for `printf()` dirctly in your code - it might look like:

```
extern int printf ( const char * format, ... );
```

but you would have to get it exactly right every time, and do it for every function you wished to use.  Would you really do that!?